# Oracle impdp remap one schema to many failed with "invalid value for parameter, 'remap_schema"

Tags: database, oracle

I created a dump file dumpfile.dmp in Oracle 12c for a schema say A from the source database, then I tried to import the dump file to several schemas say B, C, D on another database TESTDB with one command using the schema_remap option. The command looks like this:
impdp system/password@TESTDB directory=mydirectory dumpfile=dumpfile.dmp remap_schema=A:B,C,D remap_tablespace=TBS_A:TBS_B,TBS_A:TBS_C,TBS_A:TBS_D logfile=mylogfile.log.
I even put the command in .par file but I still get the same error.

It always come back with error "UDI-00014: invalid value for parameter, 'remap_schema'"
I will appreciate if anyone can tell me what I am doing wrongly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take a closer look at the syntax for REMAP_SCHEMA (and REMAP_TABLESPACE).

There is no provision for remapping one exported schema (or tablespace) to multiple destination schemas (or tablespaces).

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sutil/datapump-import-utility.html#GUID-5DA84A72-B71C-4491-9DD8-7075D9A4B04F

If your follow-up question is 'so how do I accomplish this purpose?' the answer is to run a separate import for each destination schema.

Comment: Thanks EdStevens, I thought as much, I was just looking for a shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

> tried to import the dump file to several schemas say B, C, D

> remap_schema=A:B,C,D

You can't do that; DataPump doesn't support that kind of remap. remap_schema must be a 1:1 relationship, as must remap_tablespace, and the source must be unique (i.e. you can only remap schema A once per import). Per the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sutil/datapump-import-utility.html#GUID-619809A6-1966-42D6-9ACC-A3E0ADC36523):

> Multiple REMAP_SCHEMA lines can be specified, but the source schema
> must be different for each one.

You will have to run separate imports for each target schema.

```
impdp system/password@TESTDB directory=mydirectory dumpfile=dumpfile.dmp remap_schema=A:B remap_tablespace=TBS_A:TBS_B logfile=mylogfile.log
impdp system/password@TESTDB directory=mydirectory dumpfile=dumpfile.dmp remap_schema=A:C remap_tablespace=TBS_A:TBS_C logfile=mylogfile.log
impdp system/password@TESTDB directory=mydirectory dumpfile=dumpfile.dmp remap_schema=A:D remap_tablespace=TBS_A:TBS_D logfile=mylogfile.log
```

Comment: Thanks pmdba!  I have to make do with what is available in Oracle....

Comment: I literally just described how you do it with Oracle. Datapump is the Oracle import/export utility (impdp/expdp).